# OnClick Event not Firing

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've created a very simple test page to replicate a problem I'm having within my application. Sorry if this looks long winded for something so trivial.

The .aspx page:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" text="OK" Width="60px"  UseSubmitBehavior="true" OnClientClick="saveAmendments();" />
</form>
```

In the page_load in the code behind I add an `onchange` attribute to the textbox:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        tb.Attributes.Add("onchange", "addSaveDetails('abc###123###456###test###abc###');");
    }
}
```

Which gets rendered as follows:

```
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="TestJP.aspx" id="form1">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUi3er8ht8oaCZzy2..." />
    </div>

    <div>
       <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAwKOoa..." />
    </div>

    <input name="tb" type="text" value="testtt" id="tb" onchange="addSaveDetails('abc###123###456###test###abc###');" />
    <input type="submit" name="btnOk" value="OK" onclick="saveAmendments();" id="btnOk" style="width:60px;" />
</form>
```

So if I change the value in the text box and click somewhere else on the screen the `AddSaveDetails` function fires. Then click on the button and the `saveAmendments` fires. However if you change the text and then click immediately on the button (rather than somewhere else on the screen first) and only the first (`onchange`) function fires. The `onClick` event never does. The js being called does nothing other than an alert. What could be stopping the event bubbling up to the last call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try returning true from your functions in addition to the alert.  I presume that the event action propagation is being stopped because you are returning false (or nothing, which is being interpreted as false).

Answer (score 0):

Infuriating. Thanks tvanfosson. It got me on the right track but I don't need to explicitly return true

In my js function I had a debugger; statement. That was screwing things up I.e.

I.e. Commenting out debugger fixed things..

```
function addSaveDetails(strDetails) {
debugger;
alert('func1');
//return true;
```

}

What is it about the debugger; that prevents the 2nd event firing! Argh. It turns out i actually created a problem trying to solve a non-existent one!!